# Getting an error "Object has no method 'jScrollPane'" when using it with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have the following directive that I found on another group. But there were no instructions on how to use it:

```
appModule.directive('scrollpane',function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope , element , attrs) {
            element.addClass('scroll-pane');
            element.jScrollPane();
            var api = element.data('jsp');
            scope.$watch(function(){return element.find('.'+attrs.scrollpane).length},function(length){
                api.reinitialise();
            });
        }
      };
});
```

I am trying to use it like this:

```
    <div scrollpane
        style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 760px;">
        <table">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
```

But this gives me an error as soon as my page shows:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jScrollPane'
    at link (http://127.0.0.1:81/Content/app/common/directives/autoExpand.js:37:21)
    at S (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:49:305)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:59)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:76)
    at S (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:49:246)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:59)
    at S (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:49:246)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:59)
    at h (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:43:76)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular-v1.2.0/angular.min.js:42:114 
      <div scrollpane="" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 760px;" >
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error and how I could fix it ?

Comment: Have you included jScrollpane and jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

the error is observious, element.jScrollPane(); there is no method jScrollPane() on the element object, if you you want to use jScrollPane from jquery plugin, make sure you have reference that plugin in your html.